# Ranking of alphabetical characters A-Z

Tags: c++

As part of another project that I'll be calling **PHRASEG**, which is essentially a hangman type game, I need to establish character rankings, based on a reasonably large text file. Each game will start @ 100 and by choosing vowels as an example, the score will be reduced significantly versus less frequent characters like J or Z.

Proficiency in C++ is the ultimate goal, but on that path, coding and compiler flags to produce the tightest executable are priorities. Without having delved into it deeper, but I think

```
Index = (Ch & 31) - 1;
```

is better than

```
Index = toupper (Ch) - 'A';
```

**NOTE**: *VT100 emulation is only for estethics or at least to make output a little more readable.*

**CharWeight.cpp**

```
/*
    version 5.4.0 20160609 g++ -Os -Wall -std=c++11

    On Ubuntu 16.04 using GNOME terminal 3.18.3 (132 x 43)
*/

#include  <iostream>
#include  <iomanip>
#include  <fstream>
#include  <string>
using namespace std;

/*
    Display character ranking relative to the one with the most occurences.
    In the case of the default file, there are 90,113 occurrences of the 
    letter 'S' and 31,872 of 'C'. This yields a ranking of 35 as there is 
    roughly 1/3 as many C's as S's.
*/

void Summary (unsigned Chars[], unsigned Maximum)
{
  cout << "\033[10;49H";    // Start at Row 10, Column 48

  // Display character ranking in a 3 x 9 grid with the last column only
  // having 8 rows.

  for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {    
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      int Index = col * 9 + row;
      char Ch = 'A' + Index;

      // This will exclude the 27th interation and formula works to calculate
      // essentially factional values with integers.
      if (Index < 26) {
        unsigned Weight = Chars[Index] * 100 / Maximum;

        // Samples of less that 500k characters may yield results of less
        // than 1, so those results need to be bumped
        if (!Weight)
          Weight++;

        // Display result in the format "[?]  000"    
        cout << "\033[34m[\033[1;33m" << Ch << "\033[34m]\033[1;36m";
        cout << setw (5) << Weight << "\033[6C";
        }        
      }

    // Go to new line a repeat process
    cout << "\n\033[48C";     // Indent on newline 49 spaces
    }
}

/*
    Invoked by CharWeight [Textfile]
*/

int main (int ArgC, char **ArgS) 
{
  string FName;
  ifstream Text;

  // Emulating VT100, clear screen and move cursor to initial position.
  cout << "\033[2J\033[2;47HAlphabetic character weight calculator";

  // Use filename passed by OS or America English Dictionary
  if (ArgC == 2)
    FName = ArgS [1];
  else
    FName = "/usr/share/dict/american-english";

  // Display file that will be used by algorythim.
  cout << "\033[6;18HUsing: \033[1;35m" << FName;  
  Text.open (FName);

  if (Text.is_open()) {
    unsigned Count[26] = {0};
    unsigned Max, ChrCount, FileSize, Index;
    unsigned char Ch;

    Max = ChrCount = FileSize = 0;    // Initialize variables on stack
    Ch = Text.get();                  // Read first character

    while (Text.good()) {

      // Only consider alphabetic characters in the range A-Z.
      if (isalpha(Ch)) {
        Index = toupper(Ch) - 'A';
        Count [Index]++;              // Bump occurences of this letter

        // Needed to calculate characters rank compared to the maximum
        // occurences of any letter.
        if (Count[Index] > Max)
          Max++;

        // Used to calculate what percentage of characters in file are
        // whitespace or punctuation.
        ChrCount++;
        }

      Ch = Text.get();
      FileSize++;
      }

    // Show total number of qualifying characters, total filesize and
    // ratio of qualifying charaters. 
    cout << "\033[0m --> \033[1;2;36m" << ChrCount << "\033[2;37m of ";
    cout << FileSize << " = \033[33m" << ChrCount * 100 / FileSize;
    cout << "\033[1;37m%";

    // Display 3 x 9 grid of rank results for each character
    Summary (Count, Max);     // Display summary of weight values
    }
  else
    // Usually because file doesn't exist
    cout << " \033[0;31;43m FAILED ";

  // Move cursor to last line of terminal window.
  cout << "\033[42;1H\033[0m" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `toupper` is worse than a binary and?

Comment: @BenSteffan The term `worse` may be too subjective, but considering code size wich is directly proportional to clock cycles,  stripping irrelevant bits, then adjusting to get an index from 0 to 26 far more efficient that a library call.

Comment: No, that is not always true. Performance depends on various parameters, code size being one of them. Also, what makes you think that `toupper` wouldn't be inlined at higher optimization levels? Even if there is a performance advantage, it is likely very minuscule (in comparison to the rest of the code), and it is much less readable, which is why I would advise against the bitwise and.

Comment: @BenSteffan That is one of the things I'd be most interested in seeing, is what parameters need to be passed to GCC and the resultant disassembly. So far, on this site and others, such examples haven't been forthcoming which leads me to think, is this talk about a compilers ability to optimize nothing more than rhetoric.

Comment: No, by any means not. I suggest you put your code into the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) and see what results you get with different parameters. Its a great and very handy tool.

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid importing all of `namespace std`

It's a bad habit that will [cause problems](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) in bigger programs.  Just don't.

## Don't assume a particular output device

This code writes terminal-specific escape sequences to `std::cout`, but you haven't confirmed that it's connected to a suitable terminal.  You may be connected to a file, a socket, or a different kind of terminal.  As it is, I find this kind of output hard to read:

```
[2J[2;47HAlphabetic character weight calculator[6;18HUsing: [1;35m/usr/share/dict/words[0m --> [1;2;36m3091845[2;37m of 3493701 = [33m88[1;37m%[10;49H[34m[[1;33mA[34m][1;36m   76[6C[34m[[1;33mJ[34m][1;36m    1[6C[34m[[1;33mS[34m][1;36m   98[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mB[34m][1;36m   17[6C[34m[[1;33mK[34m][1;36m    9[6C[34m[[1;33mT[34m][1;36m   59[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mC[34m][1;36m   37[6C[34m[[1;33mL[34m][1;36m   49[6C[34m[[1;33mU[34m][1;36m   30[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mD[34m][1;36m   29[6C[34m[[1;33mM[34m][1;36m   27[6C[34m[[1;33mV[34m][1;36m    9[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mE[34m][1;36m  100[6C[34m[[1;33mN[34m][1;36m   63[6C[34m[[1;33mW[34m][1;36m    7[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mF[34m][1;36m   10[6C[34m[[1;33mO[34m][1;36m   61[6C[34m[[1;33mX[34m][1;36m    2[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mG[34m][1;36m   23[6C[34m[[1;33mP[34m][1;36m   26[6C[34m[[1;33mY[34m][1;36m   15[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mH[34m][1;36m   23[6C[34m[[1;33mQ[34m][1;36m    1[6C[34m[[1;33mZ[34m][1;36m    2[6C
[48C[34m[[1;33mI[34m][1;36m   79[6C[34m[[1;33mR[34m][1;36m   64[6C
[48C[42;1H[0m
```

## Choose defaults with care

Why choose American here?

```
FName = "/usr/share/dict/american-english";
```

On Debian systems (including Ubuntu), installing any wordlist will create a symlink `/usr/share/dict/words` pointing (via `dictionaries-common`) at the administrator's choice of default.  In my case, I have `words` -> `british-english-huge`, but I don't have `/usr/share/dict/american-english`.

## Be wary of character-coding assumptions

In ASCII, in the "C" locale, this code is reasonable:

```
  if (std::isalpha(Ch)) {
    Index = std::toupper(Ch) - 'A';
```

Other locales include accented alphabetics in `std::isalpha`, and other encodings are not contiguous (the obvious example being EBCDIC).

## Think about the structure of your program

The output routine is a separate function, but the input routine is not.  Is there a good reason for the difference?

It's a good idea to focus on the data structures and the operations the code will make on the data.  If we were doing object-oriented design, we'd probably create a class with methods to update from a file, to print the contents and so on.  But we can do the same with a simple map and some free-standing functions if we prefer.

I'll argue for a `std::map<char,unsigned>` to map from a character to the total of its appearances.  This means that we don't need to know what characters are considered alphabetic in the current language, as we can simply let the runtime manage that for us.  I'll write that as

```
using histogram = std::map<char,unsigned>;
```

And we can update it given a pair of iterators:

```
template<classname Iter>
void update(histogram& h, Iter start, Iter end)
{
    for (auto it = start;  it != end;  ++it) {
        char c = *it;
        unsigned& val = h[c];
        ++val;
    }
}
```

or more compactly as

```
template<classname Iter>
void update(histogram& h, Iter start, Iter end)
{
    while (start != end)
        ++h[*start++];
}
```

Then we can read from file by using its iterator:

```
// Read all characters from file
// Return true if file successfully read, false otherwise
bool update_from_file(histogram& h, const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream input(filename);
    if (input) {
        update(h, std::istream_iterator<char>(input), std::istream_iterator<char>());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

We can make the map deal with case-folding for us, and have it map all non-alphabetics to a single entry, by providing a custom comparator:

```
struct case_insensitive_compare
{
    constexpr bool operator()(char a, char b)
    {
        if (!isalpha(a))
            return isalpha(b); // .==!, .<A
        else if (!isalpha(b))
            return false;       // A>.
        else
            return toupper(a) < toupper(b);
    }
};

using histogram = std::map<char,unsigned,case_insensitive_compare>;
```

We didn't require any changes to our update methods to take advantage of this.

---

The print method can now just iterate over the map, skipping the first element if it's not alphabetic:

```
void print_summary(std::ostream& os, const histogram& h)
{
    auto first = h.begin();
    if (!std::isalpha(first->first))
        // we have a count of non-alphabetic characters; skip it
        ++first;

    unsigned total = std::accumulate(first, h.end(), 0u,
                                     [](unsigned count, const histogram::value_type& val) {return count + val.second; });

    for (auto it = first;  it != h.end();  ++it) {
        os << char(std::toupper(it->first)) << ": " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 100.0*it->second/total << "%\n";
    }
}
```

And `main()` becomes

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    histogram h;
    if (argc < 2) {
        update_from_file(h, "/usr/share/dict/words");
    } else {
        while (*++argv)
            update_from_file(h, *argv);
    }

    print_summary(std::cout, h);
}
```

---

## Consider supporting wider alphabets

It's quite tricky to get this right, given that `/usr/share/dict/words` is probably not in the encoding you want (here, it's in ISO 8859.1, but my terminals are all UTF-8, so some conversion is required).  I was able to make it work, by assuming that we can widen `unsigned char` to `wchar_t` by simple cast (I also added some sorting, in case that's of interest):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using char_type = wchar_t;

struct case_insensitive_compare
{
    constexpr bool operator()(char_type a, char_type b)
    {
        if (!std::iswalpha(a))
            return std::iswalpha(b); // .==!, .<A
        else if (!std::iswalpha(b))
            return false;       // A>.
        else
            return std::towlower(a) < std::towlower(b);
    }
};


using histogram = std::map<char_type,unsigned int,case_insensitive_compare>;

template<typename Iter>
void update(histogram& h, Iter start, Iter end)
{
    while (start != end)
        ++h[char_type(*start++)];
}

// Read all characters from file
// Return true if file successfully read, false otherwise
void update_from_file(histogram& h, const std::string& filename)
{
    using stream_it = std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>;
    std::ifstream input(filename);
    update(h, stream_it(input), stream_it());
}

using ordered_histogram = std::vector<std::pair<char_type,unsigned>>;

ordered_histogram make_sorted_output(const histogram& h)
{
    ordered_histogram output;

    auto first = h.begin();
    if (!std::iswalpha(first->first))
        // we have a count of non-alphabetic characters; skip it
        ++first;

    std::copy(first, h.end(), std::back_inserter(output));

    std::sort(output.begin(), output.end(),
              [](const ordered_histogram::value_type& a, const ordered_histogram::value_type& b)
              { return b.second < a.second; });

    return output;
}


void print_summary(std::wostream& os, const ordered_histogram& h)
{
    unsigned total = std::accumulate(h.begin(), h.end(), 0u,
                                     [](unsigned count, const ordered_histogram::value_type& val) {return count + val.second; });

    for (auto val: h) {
        os << char_type(std::towlower(val.first)) << ": "
           << std::setw(5) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 100.0*val.second/total << "%\n";
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    histogram h;
    if (argc < 2) {
        update_from_file(h, "/usr/share/dict/words");
    } else {
        while (*++argv)
            update_from_file(h, *argv);
    }

    print_summary(std::wcout, make_sorted_output(h));
}
```

I used this with `/usr/share/dict/gaelic` as input and it produces

```
a: 15.72%
h: 11.34%
i:  9.63%
n:  6.56%
r:  6.45%
c:  6.19%
e:  5.70%
l:  5.01%
d:  4.89%
s:  4.55%
t:  4.07%
g:  3.60%
o:  3.43%
u:  2.65%
b:  2.49%
m:  2.47%
f:  1.12%
à:  1.05%
p:  0.91%
ò:  0.71%
ù:  0.58%
ì:  0.51%
é:  0.21%
è:  0.13%
ó:  0.04%
á:  0.00%
k:  0.00%
ú:  0.00%
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive feedback and especially as it applies to character codings and program structure.  This is the part of C++ that is brand new to me and I'm sure implementing and tracing through your examples with GDB will give me a better insight into what is actually happening.

Comment: control codes are simply a matter of convenience.  Should I contemplate any application moving beyond the 4 walls of my office, I'd probably use ncurses, or better yet, GNOME or KDE.

Comment: Yes, use curses or X11 for pretty output - my observation was that they were very *inconvenient* when I ran the program (with output into an Emacs `*compilation*` buffer).  Code review is full of advice - and like all advice, you can choose which to take...